# size of std::unique_ptr object with custom deleter (a lambda with capture by-ref)

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, unique-ptr

In the following code, I have a custom deleter (using a lambda which captures by-reference) for a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). I expected that the size of `std::unique_ptr` object should be the same as for a default deleter (i.e. using operator delete) as the capture is by reference. I understand that state-less functors and lambdas (with no capture) incur no size penalty then why does lambdas by-reference capture incur size penalty? Thanks in advance for explanation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class X{};

int main()
{
    // custom deleter using a state-full lambda
    double data[100]{0};
    auto lmb_sf = [&data](X* ptr){
        // do something
        std::cout<<"In custom deleter using a state-full lambda\n";
        delete ptr;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<X,decltype(lmb_sf)> ptr_sf(new X, lmb_sf);
    std::cout<<"Size of ptr_sf = "<<sizeof(decltype(ptr_sf))<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output by-reference capture (i.e. with ... lmb_sf = [&data] ...)

```
Size of ptr_sf = 16
In custom deleter using a state-full lambda
```

Output by-value capture (i.e. with ... lmb_sf = [data] ...)

```
Size of ptr_sf = 808
In custom deleter using a state-full lambda
```

Comment: Lambda captures are basically created as private members of the closeure-class generated by the compiler.

Comment: A reference is not magic. It requires space to be stored, here inside the lambda.

Comment: @Sepel References are not *required* to be stored. Here the reference fails to be optimized away. (Such optimizations are possible but costly in general.)

Comment: In fact, except the `sizeof` result, the size of `unique_ptr` instance is irrelevant to the generated code after inlining. However, the `sizeof` result of a type (with external linkage) is dominated by ABI requirements in most implementations, the compiler need to effectively transform the actual type being used to a private clone (with no other observer behavior changes) in the internal representation. This effort requires to prove the correctness of the transformation (mostly according to the as-if rules without extra specific knowledge), which is often difficult and not worthy.

Answer (score 5):

> I understand that state-less functors and lambdas (with no capture) incur no size penalty

Indeed.

> then why does lambdas by-reference capture incur size penalty?

Because a capturing lambda is stateful. That state must be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

A lambda that captures a reference must internally store the reference.

Although I don't think the size of a lambda object is specified by the standard, it must logically at least contain the address of the object captured.